# Most efficient way to save large double arrays as files in C#

Tags: c#, file-type, saving-data, large-data

I'm writing a program that is reading data from .dat files into double[,,] arrays, calculates some stuff and needs to write the arrays into a file to save them for a later usage.

These arrays can have up to [64x64x150000] elements which forces me to already load those files in small parts into the program to make use of them (otherwise the MemoryException is called). Until now I used textfiles to save smaller arrays on my harddisk but saving a [64x64x150000] array step by step fills up above >6GB per file at the end which is quiet a lot when you have to work with a lot of those .dat-files and have pretty much to keep all the .txt-files.

So I would like to know if any other filetype saves some harddisk space or if there is another possibility to save those arrays outside of my program for a later usage with less harddisk space requirement.

(I need to be able to exchange the files between different computers).

Comment: Minimally you could compress the text files.

Comment: How many digits (on average) ? Binary is 8 bytes per 'double' but `"1.1,"` takes less space. A `float` is 4 bytes binary.

Comment: How are you saving them?  Straight up binary in a structure format or are you using some highlevel format like Xml?

If you were using 100% binary stacking 8 bytes on 8 bytes directly with no fluff, it should be 4,915,200,000 bytes.

Can you change it to use a single instead?  that would reduce the size by half as a single is a 4 byte float where a double is an 8 byte float.

Also does it need to be a float at all? e.g. you could use a 4 byte integer maybe?

Comment: Also, this really depends on what kind of data your double array is representing.  Is it all data of the same type.

It might be possible to identify redundancies in the values and use a number table to Drastically reduce disk space.

E.g. you store larger whole numbers togther and have entries refer to their index (offset in file).

Comment: Why are you not just using a BinarySerializer to directly serialize the array?  Do ypu really need doubles not floats etc

Answer (score 0):

(8 B/double * (64 * 64 * 150000) double) / (10<sup>9</sup> B/GB) = 5.6 GB

So unless you either reduce to a lower precision (floats) or perform some kind of compression, you'll need 5.6 GB to store all those doubles. Reducing to floats would take 2.8 GB per file.

For each of the 64 * 64 vectors of length 150000, you may be able to perform a signal compression (depending on what the data looks like). That's a broad topic, so without knowing more all I can give you is a starting point: [Signal compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_compression).

Answer (score 0):

Either compression, or try [Binary Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b(v=vs.110).aspx).  A double can take up dozens of bytes in text, particularly depending on your encoding (1-2 per digit).  In binary, each one is exactly 8 bytes (+ however much overhead for bookkeeping, probably minimal).